# Counter with filter or subtract or similar

Tags: python, collections, filter, counter, subtraction

I have a `Counter` (from `collections`) and would like to filter out a set of unwanted items.  The result should be a new Counter (or if you like, do it in-place) containing only the items not matching the property.  I tried using `filter` on the `Counter` but then the result isn't a `Counter` anymore but a mere `list`.  I also tried subtracting a `set` of unwanted items from that `Counter` but that operation isn't implemented.  Subtracting a `Counter` works, but I don't have the second `Counter` and creating it is essentially the same task I'm trying to perform.

```
Counter([ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,6,5,4,3,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,4,5,4 ])
→ Counter({4: 6, 5: 5, 3: 4, 6: 3, 2: 2, 1: 1, 7: 1})
```

Now I want to remove all `2` and `3` values from this Counter, so the result should be

```
Counter({4: 6, 5: 5, 6: 3, 1: 1, 7: 1})
```

Here are my approaches:

```
filter(lambda x: x not in (2, 3), c)
→ [1, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

But I don't want a list.

```
c - set([ 2, 3 ])
→ TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Counter' and 'set'
```

I can use sth which iterates over the unpacked list of elements in the `Counter` like this:

```
Counter(x for x in c.elements() if x not in (2, 3))
→ Counter({4: 6, 5: 5, 6: 3, 1: 1, 7: 1})
```

but that obviously is unnecessarily costly for large amounts.

The only (not very nice) solution I found yet is sth cumbersome like this:

```
Counter({ k: v for k, v in c.iteritems() if k not in (2, 3) })
```

Is there anything better, easier, more readable I'm overlooking?

Why isn't there simply a subtraction operator for the `Counter` implemented which can be used with a `set`?

Comment: Wouldn't filtering the list and sending it to Counter work ?

Comment: If you mean sth like `Counter(filter(lambda x: x not in (2, 3), c))` then: no.  The filter iterates over the Counter which means it iterates over the keys alone; the amounts are forgotten in the process.  The result will then always have an amount of 1 for each remaining key.

Comment: I mean you filter this list `[ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,6,5,4,3,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,4,5,4 ]` and pass it to counter.

Comment: I don't have that list (except in the mini-example here); it could be enormously long.  Consider things like `Counter({ 1: 1000000 })`.  I could always create this list (as I said in the question above) by using `c.elements()`, but that I want to avoid as it is costly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `del`:

```
>>> c = Counter([ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,6,5,4,3,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,4,5,4 ])
>>> c
Counter({4: 6, 5: 5, 3: 4, 6: 3, 2: 2, 1: 1, 7: 1})
>>> del c[2]
>>> del c[3]
>>> c
Counter({4: 6, 5: 5, 6: 3, 1: 1, 7: 1})
>>>
```

Just for fun, you could substract another `Counter` with large values for the keys to remove, but better stick with `del`:

```
>>> c = Counter([ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,6,5,4,3,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,4,5,4 ])
>>> c
Counter({4: 6, 5: 5, 3: 4, 6: 3, 2: 2, 1: 1, 7: 1})
>>> c - Counter({2:sys.maxint, 3:sys.maxint})
Counter({4: 6, 5: 5, 6: 3, 1: 1, 7: 1})
```

Comment: Yeah found that as well now, thanks anyway.  The disadvantage is that it _only_ works in-place and for complete sets to remove this needs a loop (and in general I prefer functional approaches — smaller chance of introducing bugs in that world).  (_And_ I just found out that I need the version of the Counter of only the values in the set and the Counter without the set.  I'd have to copy it then and do it twice, but that's not part of the question, just my use-case here ...)

Comment: @Alfe Well, personally, I would stick with the dict comprehension `Counter({ k: v for k, v in c.iteritems() if k not in (2, 3) })` then

Comment: Yeah.  And I'll leave this question unaccepted for some time to draw a little more attention.  Eventually your answer deserves acceptance if nothing better pops up (which I doubt).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from collections import Counter
c=Counter([ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,6,5,4,3,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,4,5,4 ])
c2=Counter()
for x in c.most_common():
    if x[1]<2 or x[1]>3:
        c2[x[0]]+=x[1]
print(c2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pop - it's faster than using del or the dictionary comprehension.

```
def alt():
    C = Counter([ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,6,5,4,3,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,4,5,4])
    for k in C.keys():
        if k in (2, 3):
            del C[k]

def alt2():
    C = Counter([ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,6,5,4,3,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,4,5,4])
    for k in C.keys():
        if k in (2, 3):
            C.pop(k)

def alt3():
    C = Counter([ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,6,5,4,3,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,4,5,4])
    Counter({ k: v for k, v in c.iteritems() if k not in (2, 3) })
```

ipython:

```
>>> %timeit alt()
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.66 µs per loop

>>> %timeit alt2()
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.64 µs per loop

>>> %timeit alt3()
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.3 µs per loop
```

Comment: When using `timeit` you should only place the code-under-test into the loop.  You've put also the test data creation into it which will equalize all results, depending on how costly this step is.  But since the test data is the same in all cases, the tendency should stay intact.  Thanks for this contribution!